# Splitting multiple columns at once in R

Tags: r, split, extract, multiple-columns

I am trying to split my data frame which has 354 (a1-a354) columns. 
Example:

```
  a1 a2
1 aa aa
2 bb bb
3 cc cc
```

Currently, I am using the following code:

```
df1<- extract(df1,1, c("D","M"), "(.)(.)",convert=TRUE)
```

This works perfectly when I use it on one column at a time (i dont care about column names), however as i have 354 columns, i am trying to loop it. So far, I have tried making into a function so I can use it with lapply. I have also tried for-loop. I always get the 
Error: Data source must be a dictionary

I have been trying the following:

```
colseparator <- function(x) {
 df1<- extract(df1,x, c("D","M"), "(.)(.)",convert=TRUE)
}
```

Other thing I tried is

```
 for (x in c(7,9,11)){
      df1<- extract(df1,x, c("D","M"), "(.)(.)",convert=TRUE)
   }
```

None of my methods are working, obviously am doing something wrong.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of options.  One way would be to `paste` the rows together, create a delimiter using `gsub` and read with `read.table/read.csv`

```
read.table(text=gsub('(?<=[a-z])(?=[a-z])', ',', do.call(paste, df1),
             perl = TRUE), header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=',')
```

---

Or we could split with `strsplit` by looping over the columns and then `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(df1, function(x) do.call(rbind, strsplit(x, "(?<=.)", perl = TRUE))))
```

Comment: Hi Akrun! Thanks for the solution, the first one was working, however now it has started to give me the following output : **bold** ` 
 V1   V2   V3   V4
1  A  A D  D E  E
2  B  B E  E F   F
3  C  C F  F G  G
` It should have six columns, but it has only four

Comment: @GWhiz  It is not clear from the comments.  The example in the post seems to be in lowercase.  Now, in the comments it has uppercase.  Not clear.

Comment: Hi Akrun, I modified the code for my uppercase data: `splitcols <- read.table(text=gsub('(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])', ',', do.call(paste, subsetgeno4), 
                     perl = TRUE), header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep=',')`  which gave me the following output <br/> `V1  V2  V3 V4
<br/>1  A A D D E  E
<br/>2  B B E E F  F
<br/>3  C C F F G  G`

Answer (score 0):

The `tstrsplit()` function from the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package can be used here to split multiple columns and to return the result either in *wide* or *long* format:

#### Output in wide format

```
lapply(df1, \(x) data.table::tstrsplit(x, "") |> setNames(c("D", "M"))) |> 
  unlist(recursive = FALSE) |> 
  as.data.frame()
```

> ```
>   a1.D a1.M a2.D a2.M a3.D a3.M
> 1    a    A    e    E    h    H
> 2    b    B    f    F    i    I
> 3    c    C    g    G    j    J
> ```

#### Output in long format

```
lapply(df1, \(x) data.table::tstrsplit(x, "") |> setNames(c("D", "M"))) |> 
  data.table::rbindlist(idcol = TRUE)
```

> ```
>       .id      D      M
>    <char> <char> <char>
> 1:     a1      a      A
> 2:     a1      b      B
> 3:     a1      c      C
> 4:     a2      e      E
> 5:     a2      f      F
> 6:     a2      g      G
> 7:     a3      h      H
> 8:     a3      i      I
> 9:     a3      j      J
> ```

Note that the splitted columns are named `D` and `M` as in OP's question.
Besides `tstrsplit()` and `rbindlist()` only *base R* is used.

#### Data

In order to verify the correctness, the input dataset has been modified:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a1 = c("aA", "bB", "cC"), a2= c("eE", "fF", "gG"), a3 = c("hH", "iI", "jJ"))
df1
```

> ```
>   a1 a2 a3
> 1 aA eE hH
> 2 bB fF iI
> 3 cC gG jJ
> ```